# HTML + VBScript - Write to local Excel template

Tags: html, excel, vba, templates, vbscript

inside my html-file I use some vba-code by clicking a button. I connect to a Adodb to get some data, which is working fine. This data (stored in a recordset) should be saved in an excel-file by using an excel-template. To do this I try to open a local template:

```
Workbook.Add Template:="MyPath"
```

I also try to save this file to my local drive.

```
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "MyPath"
```

None of this is working :( Any idea?

It seems that it's not possible to access local data from my browser.

Comment: You can't use VBA in HTML, and VBScript is slightly different from VBA. Please take a look at the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info) for the VBScript tag.